# Popover delay show on mouseenter (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have created and Angularjs directive that connects a trigger to a popover. Everything work except when I want to add a delay show to the popover. I am new to javascript and angular js. So any help will be appreciated.

```
.directive('businessCardPopup', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, pop, attrs){
            scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;

            $(pop).popover({
                trigger: "manual" ,
                container: 'body',
                template: '<div class="popover" role="tooltip" style="width: 400px;">' +
                '<div class="arrow"></div>' +
                '<h3 class="popover-title"></h3>' +
                '<div class="popover-content">' +
                '<div class="data-content"></div>' +
                '</div></div>',
                html: true,
                animation:false,
                content: '<div class="col-lg-4"></div>' +
                '<div class="col-lg-8"><p>Name</p>' +
                '<p>Position</p>' +
                '<p>Telephone</p>' +
                '<p>Email</p>' +
                '<p>Skype | Twitter | LinkedIn</p>' +
                '<p>Conversation | View Profile | Follow</p></div> ',
                placement: 'top',
                delay: {"show": 2000}
            })
                .on("mouseenter", function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    $(this).popover("show");
                    $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                        $(_this).popover('hide');
                    });
                }).on("mouseleave", function () {
                    var _this = this;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                            $(_this).popover("hide");
                        }

                    }, 500);
                })


        }
    }
}
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `show: "600"` not `"show": 600`

Comment: Please see:  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage. It should be 'show': 600.
I also tried 
.on('mouseenter', function () {

                        var _this = this;
                            $(this).delay(5000).popover('show');

but it doesn't seem to delay the popover.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger type is `manual` and `delay` doesn't work with trigger type manual.

See the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage

You can try `trigger: 'focus'`.